# How to get child window opened automatically by clicking button to be the window in focus (IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, focus

I have a button on a page that is to be automatically clicked when I open the page with the following code

```
<script>
// When the page loads
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".SmallButtonItem").trigger('click')
});
</script>
```

.SmallButtonItem is the class name of the button in question. This works perfectly in Chrome and the new child window gains focus from the window the button was originally on. 
However, in IE the window with the button on it keeps the focus when the new window is opened behind it. How do I make sure the new window holds the focus in IE?

I have tried different variations of code using window.blur and window.focus including the following but I cannot get the windows to display as I want them.

```
var myWindow = window.open($(".SmallButtonItem").trigger('click'))
myWindow.focus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your child page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){ window.focus(); });
    </script>
```